# Conflicting Class Name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, sendgrid

I'm trying to use the `sendgrid-ruby` API to send emails. I have a `Attachment` model that I use to keep track of uploaded files in an AWS bucket.

I just tried running bundle install after setting

```
gem 'sendgrid-ruby'
```

in my Gemfile, but upon loading the app after installing the gem, I get the following error:

```
TypeError (superclass mismatch for class Attachment):

app/models/attachment.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:182:in `edit'
```

Is there anyway to fix this without changing the name of my model?

UPDATE:

My SendGridEmail class:

```
require 'sendgrid-ruby'
include SendGrid

class SendGridEmail

  def initialize 
  end

  def send_message
    mail = Mail.new
    mail.from = Email.new(email: 'test@example.com')
    mail.subject = 'I\'m replacing the subject tag'
    personalization = Personalization.new
    personalization.add_to(Email.new(email: 'cannon.moyer@treadmilldoctor.com'))
    personalization.add_substitution(Substitution.new(key: '-name-', value: 'Example User'))
    personalization.add_substitution(Substitution.new(key: '-city-', value: 'Denver'))
    mail.add_personalization(personalization)
    mail.add_content(Content.new(type: 'text/html', value: 'I\'m replacing the <strong>body tag</strong>'))
    mail.template_id = '7fd8c267-9a3c-4093-8989-3df163e87c47'

    sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    begin
        response = sg.client.mail._("send").post(request_body: mail.to_json)
    rescue Exception => e
        puts e.message
    end
    puts response.status_code
    puts response.body

    puts response.headers
  end

  def create_notification
    @customer.notifications.create(name: "Manually Text Job to Customer", to: "+1", notification_type: "Manual Job Notification")
  end
end
```

Comment: It's possible that this could be resolved with `require_dependency`, but hard to tell without a stack trace.

Comment: @JaredBeck I've updated the error in the question. As long as I don't `include SendGrid` I don't get the error but then I'm not able to initialize the objects because they don't exist.

Comment: @CannonMoyer you would need to reference the objects using their full name space e.g. `SendGrid::Mail`, `SendGrid::Email` (etc.) rather than `include SendGrid`

Comment: @engineersmnky I've updated the question to include my the class where I implement calls to the API. Can you please explain further?

Comment: I am not sure how to explain further. `SendGrid` has its own module name space. remove `include SendGrid` and then append `SendGrid::` to the classes needed like `Mail`, `Email`, `Content`,`Subsitution`, etc. or I guess you could `include SendGrid` inside the class declaration e.g. `class SendGridEmail; include SendGrid; #...; end` but now you would have 2 scopes `SendGridEmail` and top level `SendGrid` that refer to the same exact thing. e.g. `SendGridEmail::Email` is the same as `SendGrid::Email` so If I were you I would stick to the first suggestion to avoid ambiguity

Comment: @engineersmnky Wonderful, I've got it working now. Thanks!

Comment: Note that Ruby has some pretty strong code conventions that you should follow unless you have a very compelling reason to deviate. A) Indent with two spaces. B) Omit empty argument lists (e.g. `def initialize` instead of `def initialize()`) C) Indent the body of your `class`, don't leave it flush left. D) There's tools like [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) and [Code Climate](https://codeclimate.com) that can scan your code and make recommendations like this automatically that are worth using.

Comment: Is that API key live/production/functional? If so, might want to redact it, but also expire it and regenerate a new one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `include` messes up namespaces, so it's best to just not do that. Ruby has a singular global namespace unlike things like Python and Node, so you need to be very careful when importing.

If you `include SendGrid` and that has a `SendGrid::Attachment` class then Ruby will try and reconcile that with your `Attachment` class later, which will fail.

The best plan is to update your code to include the `SendGrid::` prefix on everything. A well-designed library will be cleanly namespaced to avoid this problem.